# iphone maps app background image

Tags: iphone, maps, background-image

can I get the background image from the Maps app (when the map is curled up and the segmented control for map modes is visible) from somewhere?

Comment: @Lex, Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Searching Google for "iphone maps background", I came to this page. As @ryyst suggested, I pulled the png files off of Maps.app. Here is the image I was searching for:

http://reedmorse.com/iphone/iPhone-SettingsTexture.png

(can't post images as I don't have 10 rep yet)

Answer (score 1):

Could you take a screenshot?  Press and hold the home button, and then press the sleep button.  The image will be put in your Photo gallery.

Comment: Do you need a screenshot to see what I mean or is that your proposal for the solution?

Comment: Well I guess it sounds like that's not a solution, but that is what I was suggesting.  Maybe I don't know what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but maybe some people might be interested in this: To get the picture, you need a jailbroken device. Then, you can copy the entire Maps.app from the device to your device via scp. Finally, use [this](http://www.newsfirerss.com/blog/?p=176) to convert the iPhone .png files to .png files you can read with your computer.

Hope this helps someone!

--Ry